# python values to bash line on a remote server

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix

So i have a script from Python that connects to the client servers then get some data that i need.

Now it will work in this way, my bash script from the client side needs input like the one below and its working this way.

```
client.exec_command('/apps./tempo.sh' 2016 10 01 02 03))
```

Now im trying to get the user input from my python script then transfer it to my remotely called bash script and thats where i get my problem. This is what i tried below.

Below is the method i tried that i have no luck working.

```
import sys
client.exec_command('/apps./tempo.sh', str(sys.argv))
```

Comment: The example of supposedly working code is syntactically invalid. What arguments does `exec_command()` take? Are you using `paramiko`?

Comment: Perhaps `'/apps./tempo.sh ' + ' '.join(sys.argv)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using Paramiko - which you should tag or include that info in your question.

The basic problem I think you're having is that you need to include those arguments inside the string, i.e.

```
client.exec_command('/apps./tempo.sh %s' % str(sys.argv))
```

otherwise they get applied to the other arguments of exec_command. I think your original example is not quite accurate in how it works;

Just out of interest, have you looked at "fabric" (http://www.fabfile.org ) - this has lots of very handy funcitons like "run" which will run a command on a remote server (or lots of remote servers!) and return you the response.

It also gives you lots of protection by wrapping around popen and paramiko for hte ssh login etcs, so it can be much more secure then trying to make web services or other things.

*You should always be wary of injection attacks - Im unclear how you are injecting your variables, but if a user calls your script with something like `python runscript "; rm -rf /"` that would have **very** bad problems for you* It would instead be better to have 'options' on the command, which are programmed in, limiting the users input drastically, or at least a lot of protection around the input variables. Of course if this is only for you (or trained people), then its a little easier.

Comment: this helps me in formatting. btw i just used 3 different variables so i will be clean no special characters from sys.argv like "[ , '"

stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command('/apps./tempo.sh %s %s %s' % (str(y),str(m),str(d)))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using `paramiko` you need to send the command as a string. It seems that you want to pass the command line arguments passed to your Python script as arguments for the remote command, so try this:

```
import sys

command = '/apps./tempo.sh'
args = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])    # all args except the script's name!
client.exec_command('{} {}'.format(command, args))
```

This will collect all the command line arguments passed to the Python script, *except the first argument which is the script's file name*, and build a space separated string. This argument string is them concatenated with the bash script command and executed remotely.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) for the `ssh` connection.

```
import paramiko
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(server, username=user,password=password)
...
ssh_client.close()
```

And If you want to simulate a terminal, as if a user was typing:

```
chan=ssh_client.invoke_shell()
chan.send('PS1="python-ssh:"\n')

def exec_command(cmd):
    """Gets ssh command(s), execute them, and returns the output"""
    prompt='python-ssh:' # the command line prompt in the ssh terminal
    buff=''
    chan.send(str(cmd)+'\n')
    while not chan.recv_ready():
        time.sleep(1)
    while not buff.endswith(prompt):
        buff+=ssh_client.chan.recv(1024)
    return buff[:len(prompt)]
```

Example usage: `exec_command('pwd')`
And the result would even be returned to you via `ssh`